# How can I make a field required only under certain conditions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have an Edit view that I use for creating and editing Users. The view has `Password1` and `Password2` fields, for password and confirmation respectively. These are not marked as required in the view model, as when editing a user, these fields are optional, only used to change a password.

I would not like to have two almost exactly the same view models, differing only by two `Required` attributes. I do have server validation for these fields, but I have a real dislike for the two-phase validation, where a user fixes all client validation errors, only to submit and wait, and then be presented with server validation errors.

Is there some way I can switch client validation on for these fields in certain cases? I know I can use jQuery to add the necessary attributes, but I was hoping for a simpler and cleaner solution.

Comment: I would check out jquery unobtrusive validation as asked about in [this other SO question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534910/what-is-jquery-unobtrusive-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [MVC Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/). It has a lovely set of conditional attributes, including `[RequiredIf]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out jquery unobtrusive validation as asked about in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534910/what-is-jquery-unobtrusive-validation).

The server-side validation can be done via ajax call for more complex validation logic.

Otherwise it seems like a [custom rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules) would be the route to take.

See [jQuery Validation documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation) for more details.