# Exception handling in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a form that it has some field and has relationship with database. I'm using entity framework I wanna handle exception before sql server send error message. For example when user enter string value in number field win or web application handle exception before sql server handle it. I wrote this code but it don't work for all the exception. For example if field was empty or has invalid type said input string is not in correct format.

```
 using (var context  = new entityTestEntities2())
        {
            try
            {
                int stNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
                var allCustomers = context.setcust(null, stNumber);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains("correct format"))
                { 
                int x= System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetExceptionCode();
                     MessageBox.Show("error number"+x.ToString()+ex.Message);
                }
             }
        }
```

Comment: I recommend `Integer.TryParse` for input from textboxes.

Comment: my question is general its only an example (int or empty field)

Comment: What does the UI look like? We're using MVC3 a lot lately, we'll build out datamodels with attributes and/or use the unobtrusive javascript validation. I'd think you'd want to do validation closer to the UI instead of letting it make a call to the database, especially in a web environment.

Comment: i do it with java script in web app but i want to produce core and place exception handle in core.i wanna find a solution for it

Comment: Validation in EF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/gg193959.aspx MVC uses Data Annotations on Entities to support jQuery unobtrusive validation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534910/what-is-jquery-unobtrusive-validation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should do is finding a architecture which is fits your solution model. In general I would do validation before creating the context. If you need more validation in your application you may want to create a validation layer for this purpose.

```
public class RuleViolation
{
    public string Property {get; set;}
    public string Message {get; set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static List<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations(string[] parameters)
    {
        List<RuleViolation> validations = new List<RuleViolation>();

        if(!int.TryParse(parameters[0], out new Int32()))
        {
            validations.Add(new RuleViolation{Message ="Input1 must be integer.", Property = "input1"});
        }
        //more validation

        return validations;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] parameters)
    {
        var validations = GetRuleViolations(parameters);

        if(validations.Any())
        {
            validations.ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x.Message));
            return;
        }

        int input1 = int.Parse(parameters[0]);

        //after all your business logic are ok, then you can go to persistence layer to hit the database.
        using (var context  = new entityTestEntities2())
        {
            try
            {
                var allCustomers = context.setcust(null, input1);
            }
            catch(SqlException exc)
            {
                //here you might still get some exceptions but not about validation.

                ExceptionManager.Log(exc);

                //sometimes you may want to throw the exception to upper layers for handle it better over there!
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope the example make more clearer the architecture about validation logic.

Answer (score 16):

You should do validation on the UI first then handle specific errors related to Entity Framework.

Create a Model and use data annotations  :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class YourViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Range(0, 15, ErrorMessage = "Can only be between 0 .. 15")]
        public int stNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

In your controller return the model to the view:

```
var model = new YourViewModel();
return View(model);
```

Bind your textbox to the model by adding the model to your view and using some tag helpers:

```
@using YourProject.WebUI.Models
@model YourViewModel  

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.stNumber )
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.stNumber )
```

Now when someone tries to enter a non numeric or a number that is out of range an error will be displayed to the user before bad data is ever sent back to the controller.

To handle Entity Framework exceptions use a try catch:

```
        try
        {
            var entity = context.yourEntity.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == custId);

            if (entity == null) return false;
            entity.value= stNumber;
            entity.ModifiedBy = userId;
            entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            Db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Ex.InnerException.Message);
            return false;
        }
```

Other Exception types include:

```
DbUpdateException
```

An error occurred sending updates to the database.

```
DbUpdateConcurrencyException
```

A database command did not affect the expected number of rows. This usually indicates an optimistic concurrency violation; that is, a row has been changed in the database since it was queried.

```
DbEntityValidationException
```

The save was aborted because validation of entity property values failed.

```
NotSupportedException
```

An attempt was made to use unsupported behavior such as executing multiple asynchronous commands concurrently on the same context instance.

```
ObjectDisposedException
```

The context or connection have been disposed.

```
InvalidOperationException
```

Some error occurred attempting to process entities in the context either before or after sending commands to the database.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of catching Exception you should catch SqlException.

SqlException has a number property that you can use:

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error number: "+e.Number + " - " + e.Message);
}
```