# Asp.Net MVC: Unobtrusive validation and scripts dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

What is the need of following jquery reference script libraries for validation in asp.net MVC?

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

And what is the meaning of 'unobtrusive validation'?

Comment: Unobtrusive validation is for client side validation used in conjunction with `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` to render error messages based on validation attributes (and prevents a form submitting if invalid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### jQuery.js:

Well, this one is an obvious dependency.

### jQuery.validate.js:

Is a library that lets you validate forms easily without the need to write the actual validation logic and event handling yourself (as it comes bundled with many 'adapters' such as  `required`, `digits`, `min/max` etc), it will automatically prevent form submission and will display the appropriate error message.

For example:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
           fullname: { required: true, minlength: 5 },
           age: { digits: true, maxlength: 2 },
           }
});
```

### jQuery.validate.unobtrusive.js:

Unobtrusive validation is aiming at sparing you from the need to explicitly set each element's validation rules in an imperative manner but rather lets you define the rules in a declarative way using `data-*` attributes.

It is called 'unobtrusive' because it lets you write semantic HTML without adding an 'intrusive' `<script>` tags for each element's desired rules.

For example:

```
<input type="text"
       name="fullname"
       data-val="true"
       data-val-required="fullname is required"
       data-val-length="minimum 5 characters"
       data-val-length-min="5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

They come just along as parts of the default templates, you don't need to use any of them if not required. For details about jQuery unobstrusive validation see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534910/what-is-jquery-unobtrusive-validation) thread.