# Client-side validation in ASP.NET MVC project is not validating the rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am using the following JS.fiddle of client-side validation within my project.
I have implemented this example as my javascript.
http://jsfiddle.net/rtglenn/VwPaR/

Currently, the fields are highlighting green when active and staying green.  However, they are not displaying red if one of the rules is broken.

Here is my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()
{ 
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <div class="float:left"> 
            @Html.Label("First Name:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @for = "fname" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person.fName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, name = "fname", id = "fname" })
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Person.fName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.  I have checked that my referenced scripts are in the correct order.

Comment: so this is a styling question only?

Comment: I copied the same Javascript I used and the above View code to an empty ASP.NET MVC project and the validation works perfectly.  So I'm not sure what the issue is when I use this code in my project.

Comment: yeah, I see.. I had to re-read your question.. so the jsfiddle is not the output of your page?.. what is the compiled output?

Comment: where is your `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Person.fName)`?

Comment: The JSFiddle is not the output, it is the example that I used for my project.   I have added a ValidationMessageFor.  However, the box still highlights green even if the rules are broken (i.e. if 1 character is entered for the field).

Comment: i feel like you're using the javascript validation approach when there's really no need. you can use data annotations and unobtrusive jquery validation

Comment: @fuzzii, look at the source of the page/view.. is the `name` attribute of the `input` (editor) for **First Name**, what you expect it to be (i.e. `fname`)??

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pYvSfG

Comment: using lowercase `name = "fname"` doesnt do anything.. you need to use proper case `Name = "fname"`

Comment: no.. it isn't then.. .it's `Person.fname` .. that's the name of your input, and that should be the name of your rule

Comment: I'm new to client-side validation, so been stuck on it for a few days now.  Hopefully I can get something to work.  Thank you JamieD77 for the dotnetfiddle, I will try out your solution and see if I can get it working :)

Comment: your editorfor additionalviewdata syntax is off a little.. you have to use this if you want to change the name and id field `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person.fName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , Name = "fname", id = "fname" }})`

Comment: @JamieD77 THANK YOU!!! This has actually fixed the issue! Didn't realize it was a syntax issue.

Comment: What are you doing changing the `name` attribute of the control! That means binding will fail! Never change the `name` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the output of `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person.fName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})`, your input `name` attributes are being assigned the values `Person.fName` and `Person.lName`, respectfully.

Your rules need to correlate to those name values.

```
 rules: {
            "Person.fName" : {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 15,
                    required: true
                },
            "Person.lName" : {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 15,
                required: true
            }
        },
```

for visual feedback, add this to your css:

```
.form-control.has-error input,
.has-error input 
{
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
```

Of course, there are alternative validation frameworks and methodologies. One of which ships with MVC: [Unobtrusive Client Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html) (older post).

Related SO Q&A: [What is jQuery Unobtrusive Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534910/what-is-jquery-unobtrusive-validation)

Comment: Thank you, although this does not fix the issue.