# what is unobtrusive in Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

**Passport.js** documentation title says

> Simple, unobtrusive authentication for Node.js

The word unobtrusive means **not conspicuous or attracting attention**.

Does it have some technical meaning? As in the case of Unobtrusive JavaScript we talk about separation of behavior from markup or structure.
In the similar context does it have some technical meaning in **Passport.js** context?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/11535101/340760

Comment: It means it wouldn't affect your regular workflow..